# Can get my data from controller using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm working on a project in asp.net mvc4. Actually I'm doing a form where I have a Select which contains a list of contacts:

```
<select id="choix_contact">
    <option>Choisir un contact</option>
        @if (ViewBag.ListeContacts != null)
           {
                foreach (var Contact in ViewBag.ListeContacts)
                     {

                        int index = ViewBag.ListeContacts.IndexOf(Contact);
                        <option value="index">@Contact.Nom</option>
                     }
           }
           else
           {
               <option>Pas de contact</option>  
           }  </select>
```

When I click on a contact in the list, I would like to get data about that contact thanks to a functions which returns me Json Data from the controller. I pass to that functions a parameter which is the index of the contact in the list. My function looks like that  :

```
public JsonResult GetContactInfo(int indexContactList)
    {
        int NumDossier = StructureData.DonneNumDossier((string)Session["Utilisateur"], (string)Session["MotDePasse"]);
        List<Contact> ListeContacts = StructureData.DonneListeContact(NumDossier);
        Contact ContactInfos = new Contact(ListeContacts[indexContactList].Nom, ListeContacts[indexContactList].Prenom, ListeContacts[indexContactList].Email, ListeContacts[indexContactList].Fonction, ListeContacts[indexContactList].TelephoneFixe, ListeContacts[indexContactList].TelephonePort);
        return Json(ContactInfos);
    }
```

So now to get data in Ajax from the controller to the view, I use that code :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#choix_contact").change(function () {
        var selectContact = document.getElementById('choix_contact');
        var index = selectContact.value;
        var url = "/Accueil/GetContactInfo";
        $.getJSON(url, { indexContactList: index }, function (data) {
            $("#nom").html(data.Nom);
            $("#prenom").html(data.Prenom);
            $("#email").html(data.Email);
            $("#fonction").html(data.Fonction);
            $("#telFix").html(data.TelephoneFixe);
            $("#telPort").html(data.TelephonePort);
        });
    });
    });
```

The thing is now that it doesn't work at all, it doesn't even go inside the ajax script... Somebody maybe has an idea ?

Comment: Which point does it reach in your JS? If it does execute the getJSON-line, what error can you see in the dev-tools (probably an error 500).

Comment: I can't see anything, nothing happens when I choose a contact in the list...

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in the JavaScript? Does it get hit? At what point does it error out? What is the error you're receiving?

Comment: 'GET http://localhost:50499/Accueil/GetContactInfo?indexContactList=index 500 (Internal Server Error)'

Comment: index must be an int and not a string, so the problem comes from the parameter..

Comment: Check my answer, the error is in your view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comments I see you're getting the following URL:

```
localhost:50499/Accueil/GetContactInfo?indexContactList=index
```

So you're passing the value `index` to your action-method. `index` is not an integer so the server will throw a 500. If you look at the error you will see something along the lines of `"cannot parse value index to System.Int32"`

What you need to is change this in your view:

```
int index = ViewBag.ListeContacts.IndexOf(Contact);
<option value="index">@Contact.Nom</option>
```

to

```
int index = ViewBag.ListeContacts.IndexOf(Contact);
<option value="@index">@Contact.Nom</option>
```

Notice the @-sign in front of `index`, this makes sure you're outputting the variable, not the string.

Apart from that, from your comment I deduct that the elements you're binding the data to are textboxes `<input type="text" />`. If that's the case you should also use the val-method instead of the html-method:

```
$.getJSON(url, { indexContactList: index }, function (data) {
            $("#nom").val(data.Nom);
            $("#prenom").val(data.Prenom);
            $("#email").val(data.Email);
            $("#fonction").val(data.Fonction);
            $("#telFix").val(data.TelephoneFixe);
            $("#telPort").val(data.TelephonePort);
        });
```

Comment: yes exactly what I did, when I open Google developer tool, I can see in that i get the JSON: 'Email: ""
Fonction: null
Nom: "MOCKAER"
Prenom: "Gilldas"
TelephoneFixe: "02 98 25 12 27"
TelephonePort: "02 98 25 12 27"' but now i don't know why i doesn't display in the textbox

Comment: If they are textboxes, you should use val instead of html. Check my edited answer

Answer (score 1):

You should allow GET requests when returning JSON which are blocked by default:

```
return Json(ContactInfos, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

NOTE 1: If you had used a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug or Chrome Developer toolbar you would have seen that your server is returning 500 status code and in the response body an exception telling you that you need to set the JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet. Exception messages are not always very meaningful but in this particular case the exception message you would have seen even contains the solution.

NOTE 2: Make sure that that the `Contact` class that you are returning from your controller action doesn't contain any circular references because you cannot JSON serialize such structures.

NOTE 3: I would recommend you using the `Html.DropDownListFor` helper instead of manually building your dropdowns as shown in your question.

Comment: What do you see as response from the server in FireBug? Also make sure that your `Contact` class doesn't contain any circular references in its object graph because you won't be able to JSON serialize it.